# Make a child component re-render on variable change in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable in useEffect hook and I'm passing it as a prop to child component. I want to render the child component on this variable change . I tried using state variable but its creating multiple re-renders though I have added dependency array.

```
     let myVar = false
     React.useEffect(() => {
       myVar  = true
     },[a])

     return (
       <childComp myVar={myVar} />
     )
```

Comment: Does it even compile? `myVar` should be undefined

Comment: modified the code.

Comment: https://medium.com/@heyamberwilkie/force-refreshing-a-react-child-component-the-easy-way-6cdbb9e6d99c is the only thing i found

Comment: put the myVar in state ... its to know react that something has changed and re-render it to have new values

Answer (score 2):

> I want to render the child component on this variable change

`myVar` is a local variable, the parent component **will not** be re-rendered when it changes. You could either:

- move the `myVar` to state, so when updated, parent re-renders so does the child

or

- use the `forceUpdate` function to *force* the parent to update when `myVar` changes.

---

```
const [, updateState] = React.useState();
const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);

let myVar = false;

React.useEffect(() => {
   myVar = true;
   forceUpdate(); // manually force the component to re-render
}, [])

return (
  <childComp myVar={myVar} />
)
```

Comment: What should be the implementation in forceUpdate

Comment: @m9m9m Its described in my answer :)